# Redefine static members in a derived class. Java

Tags: java, static, static-methods

So i was reading the book and the author says " The static members aren't involved in runtime polymorphism. You can't override the static members in a derived class, but you can redefine them."

What is that mean? Can you give me a example for this also?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you re-define a static member (either method or variable) in a sub-class, you are hiding the definition of the super-class.

```
public class Super
{
    public static void methodA()
    {

    }
}

public class Sub extends Super
{
    public static void methodA()
    {

    }
}
```

Here static `methodA` is redefined in the sub-class, but it doesn't override the `methodA` of the super class.

Calling `Sub.methodA` would invoke `Sub`'s `methodA`. If `Sub` didn't have a `methodA`, calling `Sub.methodA` would have called `Super`'s `methodA`.

Comment: Still not sure I understand, sorry. Could you give me an example?

Comment: So if the method above is not static, then it will be override not redefine, correct?

Comment: @taimeili123 Yes, if the method wasn't static, the method in the sub-class would override that in the super-class.

Answer (score 1):

If you redefine static method in subclass, its called method hiding. Static method are resolved at compile time rather than run time, and you call them based on class like say:

```
class A {
    public static void mymthod() {}
}

class B extends A {
    public static void mymthod() {}
}
```

And you call as:

```
A a = new B();
a.mymthod();//resolved at compile time and associated with class A (compiler will warn although as static method doesnt necessarily need an object to call)
```

Comment: forgive me if i am wrong, but isn't redefine a method same as override a method? if the method is not static, then it is considered override from the example you gave?

Comment: Yes that's right. But see the context where you call from Object v/s call from direct class, Runtime v/s Compile time. See that method is asscoiated with CLASS and not object. Once defined its defined and cant be changed as it's static.

Answer (score 1):

You can see for yourself with this

```
class A {

    static int x = 1;
    int y = 1;

    int f() {
        return 1;
    }

    static int sf() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class B extends A {

    static int x = 2;
    int y = 2;

    int f() {
        return 2;
    }

    static int sf() {
        return 2;
    }

}

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A b = new B();
        System.out.println("A.x=" + ((A) b).x);
        System.out.println("B.x=" + b.x);
        System.out.println("A.y=" + ((A) b).y);
        System.out.println("B.y=" + b.y);
        System.out.println("A.f() = " + ((A) b).f());
        System.out.println("B.f() = " + b.f());
        System.out.println("A.sf() = " + ((A) b).sf());
        System.out.println("B.sf() = " + b.sf());

    }

}
```

It pprints:

A.x=1
B.x=1
A.y=1
B.y=1
A.f() = 2
B.f() = 2
A.sf() = 1
B.sf() = 1

One would expect B.sf to be printed as 2 but no.

Same one would expect B.x and B.y printed as 2 but also no because fields are also not polymorphic, only functions.

I'm not sure if this has much practical value, one surely learns that after having done an error.
This is likely to be asked at worse job interviews though.

Answer (score 0):

The variable in subclass hides the variable, with the same name, in the super class.